# How to call a method from SLDS button class?

Tags: apex, visualforce, slds

How can I call a method from my controller by using an SLDS VF page. I am using a button icon, that is showing on each record returned from a search. I would like when clicked to call a method from my controller. This is what I have:

```
<td>
  <button class="slds-button slds-button_icon slds-button_icon-brand" title="Create Contact">
    <svg class="slds-button__icon slds-icon_small" aria-hidden="true">
        <use xlink:href="{!URLFOR($Asset.SLDS, 'assets/icons/standard-sprite/svg/symbols.svg#contact')}"></use>
    </svg>
    <span class="slds-assistive-text">Create Contact</span>
  </button>
</td>
```

I did try adding `action="{!newContactButton}"` inside the button class after the title, but I get an error:

> Unknown Property controller.method.

Typically with VF pages we define actionfunction, but I wonder with SLDS if I should use a different tag. If I use `apex:commandbutton`, things seem to work, but I would like to use icon button with button class tag. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can still do it using action function as below:

```
<a onclick="myActionFunction('{!record.Id}');" class="slds-button slds-button_icon slds-button_icon-brand" title="Create Contact">
        <svg class="slds-button__icon slds-icon_small" aria-hidden="true">
            <use xlink:href="{!URLFOR($Asset.SLDS, 'assets/icons/standard-sprite/svg/symbols.svg#contact')}"></use>
        </svg>
        <span class="slds-assistive-text">Create Contact</span>
    </a>

    <apex:actionFunction name="myActionFunction" action="{!myApexAction}" reRender=""  >
        <apex:param name="recordId" value=""/>
</apex:actionFunction>
```

In Apex:

```
public void myApexAction(){

    //either of the next 2 lines will work, 
    string passedParam1 = Apexpages.currentPage().getParameters().get('recordId');
    string passedParam2 = system.CurrentPageReference().getParameters().get('recordId');
    system.debug(passedParam1);
    system.debug(passedParam2);

    // implement pagereference based on recordId
}
```

Comment: This seems to be working, as I am able to call my method. Unfortunately, my method is set to route the user to another page, but yet, when I click the button, I remain on the same page. Must be missing something.
    public pageReference newExistingContactButton(){
        System.debug('See if method is executing!!!');
        pageReference newContact = new PageReference('/apex/NewContactGMS');
        return newContact;
    }

Comment: try giving page name directly in return page reference

Comment: Thank you for the info. It did not work. I think the problem is that each button appears for the row of my returned results. I have the feeling I must pass a value inside the onclick java function so it references that specific record. I am guessing this is the reason why, the page is not being routed.

Comment: modified answer for that

Comment: That is what did it. Thank you so much !!!